# meaning of "make an everlasting first impression"?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english, informal-language

i have this sentence "The competitive world has forced everyone to make an everlasting first impression". what does everlasting first impression meaning?

Comment: Do you know what the individual words mean? Best to edit your question to tell us more about what you do not understand about the phrase.

Comment: An everlasting first impression made on someone is one that lasts for ever in the memory of that person. They never forget when they first met you.

Comment: I have met plenty of people who made wonderful first impressions but turned out to be useless at their job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an idea that people get a strong opinion of you within 1 second of seeing you, or hearing you say just 1 word, or by just glancing at your web page. They think you're smart or trustworthy or a lazy or whatever. And that opinion lasts for a very long time. The exact words for this are "first impression". It's an idiom.

Adding "everlasting" before "first impression" doesn't seem very good. We really want them to have a very, very good opinion of you right away. We say "a strong first impression" for that. Everlasting doesn't even mean good -- if your webpage gives them a computer virus they will have an everlasting bad first impression of you.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, it means that if you want to succeed in this competitive world you must make a really good impression at the very beginning. If you are only middling good the first time it won't matter how much you manage to improve after that. There is no way to catch up. Your first impression will be everlasting.